# Problem compiling camera1394

Tags: ros, camera1394, camera, camera-drivers, cturtle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install the camera1394 package and I keep getting an error after running 'rosmake camer1394.' I've pasted it here:

```
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp: In member function ‘void Format7::setOperationalParameters(sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&)’:
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:440: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘binning_x’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:441: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘binning_y’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:445: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:459: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:469: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp: In member function ‘void Format7::setOperationalParameters(sensor_msgs::CameraInfo&)’:
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:440: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘binning_x’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:441: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::CameraInfo_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘binning_y’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:445: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:459: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
  /home/rheld/ros/stacks/camera1394/src/nodes/format7.cpp:469: error: ‘struct sensor_msgs::RegionOfInterest_<std::allocator<void> >’ has no member named ‘do_rectify’
```

I just ran 'svn up' in the camera1394 directory to make sure I'm using the latest version.  I still get the error above. Any tips?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9132/problem-compiling-camera1394/) by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2011-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-19**:
Are you using Diamondback or Cturtle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you are trying to compile the Diamondback (SVN trunk) version of `camera1394` against Cturtle. As you see, that does not work.

If you need the new features, run the diamondback version. An Ubuntu binary package is available: `ros-diamondback-camera-drivers`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on 2011-02-21**:
Awesome. It works perfectly now. Thanks!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-21**:
Yes, install that binary package, camera1394 is there. If you do not already have the basic diamondback distribution, you will first need to install it, see http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [Robin](https://answers.ros.org/users/148/robin/) on 2011-02-21**:
Thanks for the help! I'm new to ROS, so I'm a little unclear on the next step. Do I just sudo apt-get install that binary package? And then what? Should I still use camera1394, or does that package contain different drivers I should use? And do I need to install diamondback now?